# Groovy syntax explanation/resources

Tags: syntax, groovy

I started dabbling in groovy yesterday.  There's an example on the groovy website that I understand but I would like to know more about why it works the way it does.  What's confusing me is `who[1..-1]`.  Is this like saying `who[1..who.length()-1]`?  I can't find any documentation on this syntax.
Are there any good groovy tutorials out there besides what is on http://groovy.codehaus.org/?

```
class Greet {
  def name
  Greet(who) { name = who[0].toUpperCase() +
                      who[1..-1] }
  def salute() { println "Hello $name!" }
}

g = new Greet('world')  // create object
g.salute()              // Output "Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right -- a negative number in a range basically refers to the *end* of the list, rather than the beginning. `-x` is equivalent to `who.length()-x`.

What you're dealing with is known as *slices* in Python. (I mention the terminology because searching for something like "groovy slices" may help you find more information, although I don't know if they're actually called "slices" in reference to Groovy.) You can find more information on this particular syntax feature [here](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_collections_and_arrays).

As for other resources, I found the book *Groovy in Action* to be quite handy for learning Groovy.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll definitely look into *Groovy In Action*.

Answer (score 0):

For several languages, [PLEAC](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_groovy/index.html) is a great resource.